# How to store sugar wort?

Tags: wort, sugar

Do you guys have best plan to store longer for sugar wort to propagate yeast ?
I usually take wort after boiling step during brewing and stored at 5 C inside 20 liter container.
Or
Boil with DME for starter ?

Comment: I know this is not the answer to your question per se, but I've always found that storing starter wort is not really worth it. Chucking some DME into a pot of water, boiling and cooling it is so trivial that it's not really worth the hassle of trying to store a starter wort that is sufficiently sterile so as to reliable.

Comment: But for me and my company i cant use DME to use in a starter !! .. now i m trying with wort after boiling step where wort contains malt and hops where liquid Brix is around 10 and SG is 1.050.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy and convenient way to store sugary wort in order to make futur starter is to freeze it.
You can store your frozen wort in your freezer for a long time (i'd say at least 6 month).

I would advice you to separate your wort into little smaller parts so that you can only unfreeze what's needed when it's needed.

Comment: So u mean if i dont freeze,it'd not last for 6 months? Plz dont mind my question!..

Comment: Best answer, since it is the simplest.

Comment: Valuable answer !! Points taken!!

Comment: I've frozen in the past and have had no ill effects using it in a starter.  Aside from cracking one of my juice jugs trying to remove a giant ice cube into a pot...

Comment: @ThantHtooAung I said 6 month as a rule of thumb for food stored in the freezer but I woiuld guess you can keep it much longer

Answer (score 1):

I heard pressure cooking the wort is a great way to make your wort storable for couple of months: https://www.themadfermentationist.com/2014/11/pressure-canning-starter-wort.html

Never tried it myself, due to the lack of a pressure cooker.

Comment: Ok bro i ll check it out :D 
Thx for your information and time !

Answer (score 1):

The method I’ve yet only heard of, used by breweries and homebrewers alike, is to *boil the wort for 10-15 minutes and freeze it*. This would also is in line with traditional German Reinheitsgebot.

Personally I use DME for starters.

Best of luck!

**Edit:**
Some yeast labs suggests using a wort of 1.040 to avoid ethanol production when making a starter. Higher gravity may inhibit cell growth.

Comment: Unfortunately i dun hav DME so i need to use wort after boiling step :(

Answer (score 0):

**Keg it.**

Put your boiled wort right into a corney while hot. This sanitizes the keg much like heat does in canning.

Store it with your beer in the keezer.

Use a fresh sanitizes picnic tap and line when drawing for use. Attach cO2 at 2 psi just enough to push it. Then remove a fittings.

If done right you don't even need a boil when doing starters. But bringing the wort to a boil for 3-4 minutes and chilling insures sanitation.

**I'll do 5 gallon wort brews, or use second running s and bump to 1.040 with extracts**

Comment: This answer assumes too much that everyone who wants to homebrew will be kegging, or even would want to invest in kegging gear.

Comment: My company is brewing now 1500 liter sometimes too !! So i need to start with 20 grams of dry yeast to reach out the amount to brew for 500 liter at least within 5 days and it is now a struggle for me !!

Comment: @chthon I understand not everyone kegs. But if you brew enough to want to pre batch starter wort, you're probably ready. If you're doing starters at all you're probably doing 5 gallon or better volume sizes. If your not kegging the same canning principles apply, just use mason jars.